# Run Xcode 6.x on macOS Sierra 10.12

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I downloaded xCode 6 from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/, but it crashes after start.

> ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7718/IDEKit/CommandsAndSelection/IDECommandManager.m:72
>   Details:  Error looking up handler class for extension
>   'Xcode.IDEKit.CmdHandler.ShowViewFrames' in plug-in
>   'com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerUI':

The thing is - I have to run app on iOS 7.x simulator, which is unavailable from Xcode 7 and above. Is there any workaround on this topic? Is there any other way to run iOS 7 simulator from newer versions of Xcode?

Comment: In addition to what was written below, I really suggest dropping support for iOS 7. It is a very outdated OS, and is not worth the effort.

Comment: Totally agree with you, but it's not my decision - maintain iOS 7 :)

Comment: refer: http://indiestack.com/2016/08/xcode-6-on-sierra/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the simulator runtime and modern Apple operating systems are incompatible. The iOS 7.1 simulator runtime is only supported on Yosemite and below. So even if you manager to install and run Xcode 6, you will still not be able to run the simulator runtime.

I suggest splitting your hdd into a second partition and installing Yosemite or Mavericks on it, and using Xcode 6 there.